# when trying to update or disable the cache site does not work magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, cache

I am new in Magento, i need help When trying to update or disable the cache site does not work magento 2.

Comment: check Magento logs and browser's console log

Comment: file "system.log"
[2018-06-01 21:35:51] main.WARNING: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'header.panel'. [] []

Comment: file "system.log"
[2018-06-02 14:31:31] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/ru_RU/WeltPixel_DesignElements/js/aos.js.map' [] []

Comment: file "system.log"
[2018-06-02 14:32:27] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/ru_RU/WeltPixel_DesignElements/css/aos.css.map' [] []

Comment: I think those file should not have '.map'.

Comment: Also check 'header.panel' is that exist or not. is there any other logs?

Comment: [2018-05-17 17:46:38] main.WARNING: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'header.panel'. [] []